# How to get Children Objects of a DataTemplate through the use of ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a DataTemplate in Page.Resources representing the structure of Tables and their associated number in a Restaurant:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Table">
    <RelativePanel x:Name="container" Height="40" Width="40">
        <TextBlock x:Name="number" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In XAML I use ContentControl because I have to repeat the same structure  avoiding copy-paste:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Table}" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="100"/>
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Table}" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="300"/>
```

Then I have a Button to add new ContentControl(Table) dinamically in code-behind

```
private void NewTable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentControl tavolo = new ContentControl();
            tavolo.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Table"];
            //here i Want to take the textblock called "number" and change his text.
            Canvas.SetTop(tavolo, 150);
            Canvas.SetLeft(tavolo, 150);
            sala.Children.Add(tavolo);
        }
```

But if I want to change the text of textblock called "number" in this function(only for that new Table, not for all the other ContentControl), what should i do? What is the resolution of this problem using databinding?

Moreover, what is the best way to resolve the problem of "copy-paste"? Should I use other structures like Usercontrols?
I hope that Someone will reply to all theese questions. I'm really confused and stucked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get Children Objects of a DataTemplate through the use of ContentControl

I found you add the `ContentControl` dynamically in code-behind. For this scenario, the better way is use [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper) to  find the child.

```
public static DependencyObject MyFindChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = MyFindChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void AppBar_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl tavolo = new ContentControl();
    tavolo.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Table"];
    //here i Want to take the textblock called "number" and change his text.
    Canvas.SetTop(tavolo, 150);
    Canvas.SetLeft(tavolo, 150);
    tavolo.Loaded += Tavolo_Loaded;  
    sala.Children.Add(tavolo);
}

private void Tavolo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textblcok = MyFindChildByName(sender as ContentControl, "number") as TextBlock;
    textblcok.Text = "New Content";
}
```

Comment: Thanks too much for have helped me! It works very well and this a really smart solution. But now I have another question: Could you tell me how to obtain the ContentControl parent starting from the textblock "number"? In general, how to navigate from the children to the parents